# If the Yoneda lemma essentially says that $\text{Hom}(\text{Hom}(\cdot, x), A) \simeq A(x)$, then what about higher iterates of $\text{Hom}$?

Tags: category-theory, functors, yoneda-lemma, natural-transformations

Assume that the $C$ in $\text{Hom}_C(x,y)$ can always be inferred from $x,y$ so that we can change our notation to $\text{H}(x,y) := \text{Hom}_C(x,y)$

Then the Yoneda lemma "looks at a single step of iteration" of $\text{H}$:

$\text{H}(\text{H}(\cdot, x), A) \simeq A(x)$

is the basic statement of Yoneda.  Do isomorphisms of higher iterates of $\text{H}$ now become trivial under Yoneda's lemma, or is there a finite iteration of $\text{H}$ in either argument that yields an interesting isomorphism?

For example, what can we say about:

$$
\text{H}(\text{H}(\text{H}(\cdot, x), B), A)
$$
is it just that it's isomorphic to $H(B(x), A)$ because of yoneda?  Or is there something else we can say?

---

Following along the lines of proof of Yoneda in *Categories & Sheaves*, we have a sequence of maps:

$$
\text{H}(\text{H}(\text{H}(\cdot, x), B), A) \to \text{H}(H(H(x,x), B(x)), A(x))
$$

but in order to use the identity trick we $B(x) = \text{Hom}(x,x)$ as well.  So what about $B = \text{Hom}(x, \cdot)$.  Then we have that we're looking at the finite iterate:

$$
\text{H}(\text{H}(\text{H}(\cdot, x), \text{H}(x, \cdot)), A) \simeq A \circ \text{H}(x,x)
$$

Comment: $\mathsf{Hom}(-,X)$ and $\mathsf{Hom}(X,-)$ are objects of different categories, so you can't talk about the set of arrows between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be careful to distinguish both $Hom$ functors: the inner one in the Yoneda lemma is just in your category $C$, while the outer one is in the functor category $Set^{C^{op}}$. Adding another $Hom$ means that you would have to take morphisms between natural transformations (called modifications), which are trivial in $Cat$ (see [this Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32765/whats-after-natural-transformations)), so "Yoneda-like" expressions with higher iterates of $Hom$ are always  trivial, regardless of Yoneda's lemma.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fac that the higher isomorphisms are just special cases of the original Yoneda isomorphism since I'm just varying the arguments.